# Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using

Tags: express, stripe-payments

Why am I encountering errors when using the test card number "4242424242424242" on my newly created Stripe account, even though I've added the required `Secret key` to my Node Express routes? and also I have tested with a similar card number available in the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/testing?testing-method=card-numbers). but it give error
`Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using`.

But it works in my old `Secret key`.

Answer (score 4):

Stripe flags this in their documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/testing?testing-method=card-numbers#test-code

> We don’t recommend using card numbers directly in API calls or
> server-side code, even in test mode.

I understand you're working in test mode right now but think about the production scenario: unless you're PCI compliant, your server-side code should never have access to a customer's raw card number. In production, you'll likely use Stripe Checkout or the PaymentElement to collect a customer's card number. The card number will be shared directly with Stripe, and Stripe will create a PaymentMethod ID to represent that real card. The PaymentMethod IDs in Stripe's [testing doc](https://stripe.com/docs/testing?testing-method=payment-methods#cards) are what you should use server side.

Answer (score 2):

Basically its not recommended in the newest version of Stripe instead you can just pass the [stripe test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing?testing-method=tokens#cards) provided by stripe for testing purposes

```js
export const addNewCard = async(req:Request,res:Response)=>{
    try {
     
        const card = await stripe.customers.createSource(
            req.body.customer_id,
            {source: 'tok_mastercard'}
          );
        res.status(200).send({ card:card.id });
    } catch (error:any) {
        res.status(400).send({success:false,msg:error.message});
    }
}
```

In this code you just have to pass the generated customer ID and `{source: 'tok_mastercard'}` already have card token, its having details of Mastercard.
you can use other [cards by brand](https://stripe.com/docs/testing?testing-method=tokens#cards)

Answer (score 1):

> But my coworker's test account isn't PCI compliant either, so I'm
> still curious as to why this works with his secret key, but not mine.

This error is a feature of new Stripe accounts following changes to how you can enable Server-side payment method collection :
[https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#:~:text=If%20you%20continue%20to%20send,implement%20to%20remain%20PCI%20compliant](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#:%7E:text=If%20you%20continue%20to%20send,implement%20to%20remain%20PCI%20compliant).
This would be normal if your coworker's Stripe account is older than yours.

You'll have to contact Stripe support and submit a SAQ D form before this error can be bypassed on your account.

Or, as suggested above, use test tokens, or don't pass card information server-side, but client-side using functions documented here:
https://stripe.com/docs/js

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended in Stripe's newest API version.

Instead do

```
// https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "YourKey";

var options = new CardCreateOptions
{
  Source = "tok_visa_debit", //https://stripe.com/docs/testing?testing-method=tokens
};
var service = new CardService();
service.Create("YourStripeUserId", options);
```

```
// Example: this method will create new customer with a payment card
public async Task<Customer> AddStripeCustomerAsync(Customer customer, CancellationToken ct)
{
    // Set Customer options - We need to create the customer first as we will need the id 
    CustomerCreateOptions customerOptions = new CustomerCreateOptions
    {
        Name = customer.Name,
        Email = customer.Email,
    };

    // Create customer at Stripe
    Customer stripeCustomer = await _customerService.CreateAsync(customerOptions, null, ct);

    // Set Stripe Token options based on customer data
    var cardTokenOptions = new CardCreateOptions
    {
        Source = "tok_visa_debit",
    };

    // Create new Card Token
    var cardToken = await _cardService.CreateAsync(stripeCustomer.Id.ToString(), cardTokenOptions, null, ct);

    // Return the created customer at Stripe (good for testing, to see if the request gone through)
    return new Customer(stripeCustomer.Name, stripeCustomer.Email, stripeCustomer.Id);

    /*In the code above we are creating a new customer and the customer's credit card at Stripe through the API. 
     * We start off by creating a new token object that contains the customer's credit card details.*/
}
```

[Card created against user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PTfd.png)