# The payment process can't be done due to security issues

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I'm a beginner in laravel and I'm trying to make a payment API using laravel and stripe. I created a function to do it following stripe docs and youtube tutorials but I keep getting an error I can't solve although I searched a LOT. The project delivery is very soon, I need help, please.

```
$stripe = new StripeClient(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));
            $create_card_token = $stripe->tokens->create([
                'card' => [
                  'number' => $request->number,
                  'exp_month' => $request->exp_month,
                  'exp_year' => $request->exp_year,
                  'cvc' => $request->cvc,
                ],
              ]);
              Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'));
              $create_charge = $stripe->charges->create([
                'amount' => $request->amount,
                'currency' => 'egp',
                'source' => $create_card_token->id,
              ]);  
            return Response([
                'status' => $create_charge->status,
            ], 201);
```

This is the error I always get:

```
Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583126/sending-credit-card-numbers-directly-to-the-stripe-api-is-generally-unsafe-we-s)